# SQL N x NのjoinにてList in ListのQueryをしたい

Tags: mysql, sql

3つのtableがあります。

```
product
id | name
1  | hoge
2  | fuga
```

---

```
tag
id | name
11 | tag1
22 | tag2
```

---

```
map_product_tag
product_id | tag_id
1          | 11
1          | 22
2          | 22
```

---

期待する結果

```
product_id | tags
1          | [{11,tag1},{22,tag2}]
2          | [{22,tag2}]
```

---

sql

```
select 
  product.id as proruct_id, 
  product.name as product_name, 
  tag.id as tag_id,
  tag.name as tag_name
from product
left join 
  map_product_tag 
on 
  product.id = map_product_tag.product_id
left join tag on map_product_tag.tag_id = mst_tag.id;
```

この場合結果は

```
+--------------------------------------+--------------+--------------------------------------+------------------+
| proruct_id                           | product_name | tag_id                               | tag_name         |
+--------------------------------------+--------------+--------------------------------------+------------------+
| 1                                    | hoge         | 11                                   | tag1             |
| 1                                    | fuga         | 22                                   | tag2             |
+--------------------------------------+--------------+--------------------------------------+------------------+
```

となります。
product_idが同じ場合、tag_idを"11,22"のように1行で取得したいです.
※ [{tag_id, tag_name}]のようにできることが一番望ましいです。

Comment: 操作として文字列の結合に該当するので、データベースエンジンが何かを指定しないと回答できません。質問にご利用のデータベース情報を追記していただけますでしょうか。

Comment: @YukiInoue ありがとうございます。tagに追記しました。mysql 5.7です。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ご希望の書式と完全に一致しないかもしれませんが、JSON_OBJECTAGGがヒントになるかもしれません。

```
select
   product_id,
   JSON_OBJECTAGG(tag_id, tag_name) as tags
from
   (
      select
         product.id as product_id,
         product.name as product_name,
         tag.id as tag_id,
         tag.name as tag_name 
      from
         product 
         left join
            map_product_tag 
            on product.id = map_product_tag.product_id 
         left join
            tag 
            on map_product_tag.tag_id = tag.id 
   )
   as x 
group by
   product_id
```

実行結果

```
product_id  tags
1   {"11": "tag1", "22": "tag2"}
2   {"22": "tag2"}
```

次のようにJSON_ARRAYAGGを使う方が希望の書式に近いかもしれません。

```
   JSON_ARRAYAGG(JSON_ARRAY(tag_id, tag_name) )  as tags
```

実行結果

```
product_id  tags
1   [[11, "tag1"], [22, "tag2"]]
2   [[22, "tag2"]]
```